# How to paste multiple environment variables in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to add multiple environment variables in IntelliJ? When one sends me a list of variables I can add them one by one by clicking `+` in this window

[image]

But it's quite annoying to do for 10 or 20 variables every time. I can copy all variables from `Environment variables` field but we cannot paste there. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible to paste all environment variables at once in this screen but they need to be in a specific format.

Click on the `...` button to the right of environment variables to show the dialog you have in your first screenshot.

Now you can use the `Paste` button but the values in your clipboard have to be in a specific format for pasting to work. In your case that clipboard info would be something like this:

```
APP_PORT=8080
DB_URL=jdbc:mysql...
DB_USER=javausers
DB_PASSWORD=javausers
APP_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

Try copying the value above and use the paste button (not `Ctrl+v`). If you don't have your data in this format you can try formatting it using a text replace tool online.

Also if you select all of the values in that dialog and click the copy button you can get the values in the same format that will work with importing. Warning: clicking `Ctrl+c` will not copy the values in the same format as the copy button in the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "Paste" button at the bottom of the variables list.

Comment: This works good for one variable but is it possible to do it for 10 variables in buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just:

1. Click on the three dots (`...`) button of the **Environment variables** option. On the Windows version, the button is a little folder icon.
2. Select all the variables on the showed popup (`name` and `value`) and click on the "**Copy**" button. Close the popup.
3. Choose the other configuration, open his **Environment variables** option and click on the "**Paste**" button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the (...) option is available in the community edition also. 
This is how i was able to add them to the configuration. Just select the environment variables you want to import into the desired configuration.
E.g: If you have variables like

```
min_instance_count: 1
max_instance_count: 2
min_memory: 2 
max_memory: 2
```

Replace the colons/other delimiters with = :

```
min_instance_count= 1
max_instance_count= 2
min_memory= 2  
max_memory= 2
```

Now import the variables by copy-pasting (the clipboard sign).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply paste a `;` concatenated list of environment variables (and their values) into the `Environment Variables` dialog box.

E.g. paste in:

`AWS_DYNAMO_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4569;AWS_REGION=us-east-1;sample_var=sample`

and get:

[image: image of environment variables successfully pasted in]